# Auto contact add/sorter/reply works but misses last received email

Tags: vba, outlook

new to these forums, looks like a lot of knowledgeable people are around to help!
I am pretty new to VBA for outlook, and VBA in general.

I have pieced together some code, using examples I have found after LOTS of research, and have tailored it to do what I need it to do. It is very messy right now as I am just commenting out things that I don't need and am just adding in things to test. It works and does everything I need it to do, except it misses the last received email. I haven't cleaned the code up yet because I like having what WAS there around for reference.

This code should
upon receiving a new email

1) check unread mail to see if email contains addresses already in contacts
if not it will add the contact, and move the email received to specified folder
2) auto reply and mark as read

The code (as far as I can tell) is functioning properly except for one little detail:

It consistently misses the last received email if more than one email is received at a time. I have read, and read, and read, and just cant wrap my head around WHY that last email is missed. Any help here, suggestions, ideas, or a point in the right direction would be greatly appreciated!

I am using Outlook 2000 and the relevant code I have put together is below

```
Private WithEvents Items As Outlook.Items
Private Sub Application_Startup()
  Dim olApp As Outlook.Application
  Dim objNS As Outlook.NameSpace
  Set olApp = Outlook.Application
  Set objNS = olApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
  ' default local Inbox
  Set Items = objNS.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Items
End Sub

 Private Sub Items_ItemAdd(ByVal item As Object)
 On Error GoTo ErrorHandler
  Dim msg As Outlook.MailItem

  If TypeName(item) = "MailItem" Then
    Set msg = item
    'MsgBox ("New Join!")
   ' MsgBox msg.Subject
    Call AddAddressesToContactsAuto
   ' Call find_unread              '''''ADD THIS BACK
   ' MsgBox msg.Body
  '  test field
'    Dim oout As Object
 ' Dim omsg As Object

'  Set oout = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
 ' Set omsg = oout.CreateItem(0)

'  With omsg
 '    .To = msg.Subject
 '    .CC = ""
 '    .BCC = ""
  '   .Subject = Thanks
  '   .Body = (msg.Body & "Thank you for joining Club PFM! You will be receiving your first newsletter with your special Club PFM offer within the next 7 days!")
  '   .Display
  ' End With

  ' testing
  ' If omsg.Sent Then
   '   MsgBox (" Sent ")
  ' Else
   '  MsgBox (" Not Send ! ")
  ' End If

 ' Set oout = Nothing
 ' Set omsg = Nothing

   ' end test field
  End If
ProgramExit:
  Exit Sub
ErrorHandler:
  MsgBox Err.Number & " - " & Err.Description
  Resume ProgramExit
 End Sub

Public Sub AddAddressesToContactsAuto()
Dim folContacts As Outlook.MAPIFolder
Dim folContacts2 As Outlook.MAPIFolder
Dim folContacts3 As Outlook.MAPIFolder
Dim colItems As Outlook.Items
Dim colItems2 As Outlook.Items
Dim colItems3 As Outlook.Items
Dim oContact As Outlook.ContactItem
Dim oContact2 As Outlook.ContactItem
Dim oContact3 As Outlook.ContactItem
Dim oMail As Outlook.MailItem
Dim obj As Object
Dim oNS As Outlook.NameSpace
Dim folder As MAPIFolder
Dim myDestFolder As Outlook.MAPIFolder


Dim response As VbMsgBoxResult

Dim bContinue As Boolean

Dim sSenderName As String
Dim emailz As String

On Error Resume Next

Set oNS = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")
Set folContacts = oNS.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderContacts)
Set folContacts2 = oNS.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderContacts).Folders("Awaiting Invitation")
Set folContacts3 = oNS.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderContacts).Folders("Added To Mail List")
Set colItems = folContacts.Items
Set colItems2 = folContacts2.Items
Set colItems3 = folContacts3.Items
Set folder = oNS.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)         '.Folders("Awaiting Invitation")
Set myDestFolder = oNS.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Folders("Awaiting Invitation")

For Each obj In folder.Items

If (obj.Class = olMail) And (obj.UnRead) Then

Set oContact = Nothing
Set oContact2 = Nothing
Set oContact3 = Nothing

bContinue = True
sSenderName = ";"

Set oMail = obj

sSenderName = oMail.Body
emailz = oMail.Subject
If sSenderName = ";" Then
sSenderName = oMail.Body
emailz = oMail.Subject
End If

Set oContact = colItems.Find("[E-mail] = '" & emailz & "'")
Set oContact2 = colItems2.Find("[E-mail] = '" & emailz & "'")
Set oContact3 = colItems3.Find("[E-mail] = '" & emailz & "'")

'start checks
'default folder
If Not (oContact Is Nothing) Then

response = MsgBox(emailz & " Already exists in contacts! Add anyways?", vbQuestion + vbYesNo, "Contact Adder")
If response = vbNo Then
bContinue = False
End If
End If
'awaiting invitation
If Not (oContact2 Is Nothing) Then

response = MsgBox(emailz & " Already exists in contacts! Add anyways?", vbQuestion + vbYesNo, "Contact Adder")
If response = vbNo Then
bContinue = False
End If
End If
'added to mail list
If Not (oContact3 Is Nothing) Then

response = MsgBox(emailz & " Already exists in contacts! Add anyways?", vbQuestion + vbYesNo, "Contact Adder")
If response = vbNo Then
bContinue = False
End If
End If

'end checks
If bContinue = True Then
oMail.Move myDestFolder  'ADDED THIS REMOVE IF YOU BREAK IT!!!
Set oContact = colItems2.Add(olContactItem)
With oContact
.Body = "Club PFM Member!"
.Email1Address = emailz
.BusinessAddress = emailz
.FullName = sSenderName
.Save
End With
'testing start
'testing end
End If
End If
emailz = ""
Next


Set folContacts = Nothing
Set folContacts2 = Nothing
Set folContacts3 = Nothing
Set colItems = Nothing
Set colItems2 = Nothing
Set colItems3 = Nothing
Set oContact = Nothing
Set oContact2 = Nothing
Set oContact3 = Nothing
Set oMail = Nothing
Set obj = Nothing
Set oNS = Nothing
Call find_unread

End Sub

Sub find_unread()
    On Error GoTo eh:
    ' I want to be able to catch up by reading all my unread messages
    Dim ns As Outlook.NameSpace
    Dim folder As MAPIFolder
    Dim item As Object
    Dim msg As MailItem
    'for sending mail
    Dim oout As Object
    Dim omsg As Object
    'end sending mail
      Dim Thanks As String
    ' Open the inbox folder
    Set ns = Session.Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set folder = ns.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Folders("Awaiting Invitation")

    ' Loop through items in the inbox folder
    For Each item In folder.Items
        DoEvents
        If (item.Class = olMail) And (item.UnRead) Then
            ' This message has not been read.  Display it modally
            Set msg = item
            item.UnRead False
            Thanks = ("Thanks for joining Club PFM!")
            MsgBox ("7 Day notice sent to: " & msg.Subject)
            'create auto response
            Set oout = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
  Set omsg = oout.CreateItem(0)

  With omsg
     .To = msg.Subject
     .CC = ""
     .BCC = ""
     .Subject = Thanks
     .Body = (msg.Body + "Thank you for joining Club PFM! You will be receiving your first newsletter with your special Club PFM offer within the next 7 days!")
     .Display
   End With
   'end response
            'try calling other operations, see if they work!!
            'does not work in this fashion, try putting entire code here, then call this on new mail event

            'Call AddAddressesToContacts
            'end calling operations
            ' uncomment the next line to have it only find one unread
            ' message at a time
            'Exit For
        End If
    Next

    ' If you uncommented the line to read individual messages,
    ' comment the next line so you don't get a message box
    ' every single message!

    MsgBox "All messages in Inbox are read", vbInformation, "All Read"
    Exit Sub
eh:
    MsgBox Err.Description, vbCritical, Err.Number
End Sub
```

Ok niton thanks for the info, I have revised relevant code and it is below, your idea has fixed some of my problems, if I comment out "find_unread" ... "AddContactsToAddressesAuto" works 100% of the time flawlessly! Now my problem is still similar, with the changes below, the last received email is left behind in the inbox, so its something in "find_unread" i think that is messing things up, I just cant figure out what!

outlook 2000
vba update

```
Public Sub AddAddressesToContactsAuto()
Dim folContacts As Outlook.MAPIFolder
Dim folContacts2 As Outlook.MAPIFolder
Dim folContacts3 As Outlook.MAPIFolder
Dim colItems As Outlook.Items
Dim colItems2 As Outlook.Items
Dim colItems3 As Outlook.Items
Dim oContact As Outlook.ContactItem
Dim oContact2 As Outlook.ContactItem
Dim oContact3 As Outlook.ContactItem
Dim oMail As Outlook.MailItem
Dim obj As Object
Dim oNS As Outlook.NameSpace
Dim folder As MAPIFolder
Dim myDestFolder As Outlook.MAPIFolder


Dim response As VbMsgBoxResult

Dim bContinue As Boolean

Dim sSenderName As String
Dim emailz As String

On Error Resume Next

Set oNS = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")
Set folContacts = oNS.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderContacts)
Set folContacts2 = oNS.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderContacts).Folders("Awaiting Invitation")
Set folContacts3 = oNS.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderContacts).Folders("Added To Mail List")
Set colItems = folContacts.Items
Set colItems2 = folContacts2.Items
Set colItems3 = folContacts3.Items
Set folder = oNS.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)         '.Folders("Awaiting Invitation")
Set myDestFolder = oNS.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Folders("Awaiting Invitation")

'For Each obj In folder.Items
For I = folder.Items.Count To 1 Step -1
    Set obj = folder.Items(I)
If (obj.Class = olMail) And (obj.UnRead) Then

Set oContact = Nothing
Set oContact2 = Nothing
Set oContact3 = Nothing

bContinue = True
sSenderName = ";"

Set oMail = obj

sSenderName = oMail.Body
emailz = oMail.Subject
If sSenderName = ";" Then
sSenderName = oMail.Body
emailz = oMail.Subject
End If

Set oContact = colItems.Find("[E-mail] = '" & emailz & "'")
Set oContact2 = colItems2.Find("[E-mail] = '" & emailz & "'")
Set oContact3 = colItems3.Find("[E-mail] = '" & emailz & "'")

'start checks
'default folder
If Not (oContact Is Nothing) Then

response = MsgBox(emailz & " Already exists in contacts! Add anyways?", vbQuestion + vbYesNo, "Contact Adder")
If response = vbNo Then
bContinue = False
End If
End If
'awaiting invitation
If Not (oContact2 Is Nothing) Then

response = MsgBox(emailz & " Already exists in contacts! Add anyways?", vbQuestion + vbYesNo, "Contact Adder")
If response = vbNo Then
bContinue = False
End If
End If
'added to mail list
If Not (oContact3 Is Nothing) Then

response = MsgBox(emailz & " Already exists in contacts! Add anyways?", vbQuestion + vbYesNo, "Contact Adder")
If response = vbNo Then
bContinue = False
End If
End If

'end checks
If bContinue = True Then

obj.Move myDestFolder  'ADDED THIS REMOVE IF YOU BREAK IT!!!
Set oContact = colItems2.Add(olContactItem)
With oContact
.Body = "Club PFM Member!"
.Email1Address = emailz
.BusinessAddress = emailz
.FullName = sSenderName
.Save
End With
'testing start
'testing end
End If
End If
emailz = ""
Next


Set folContacts = Nothing
Set folContacts2 = Nothing
Set folContacts3 = Nothing
Set colItems = Nothing
Set colItems2 = Nothing
Set colItems3 = Nothing
Set oContact = Nothing
Set oContact2 = Nothing
Set oContact3 = Nothing
Set oMail = Nothing
Set obj = Nothing
Set oNS = Nothing
Call find_unread

End Sub

Sub find_unread()
    On Error GoTo eh:
    ' I want to be able to catch up by reading all my unread messages
    Dim ns As Outlook.NameSpace
    Dim folder As MAPIFolder
    Dim item As Object
    Dim msg As MailItem
    'for sending mail
    Dim oout As Object
    Dim omsg As Object
    Dim obj As Object
    'end sending mail
    Dim Thanks As String
    ' Open the inbox folder
    Set ns = Session.Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set folder = ns.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Folders("Awaiting Invitation")

    ' Loop through items in the inbox folder
   'For Each item In folder.Items
For I = folder.Items.Count To 1 Step -1
    Set obj = folder.Items(I)
        DoEvents
        If (obj.Class = olMail) And (obj.UnRead) Then
            ' This message has not been read.  Display it modally
            Set msg = obj
            obj.UnRead False
            Thanks = ("Thanks for joining Club PFM!")
            MsgBox ("7 Day notice sent to: " & msg.Subject)
            'create auto response
            Set oout = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
            Set omsg = oout.CreateItem(0)

  With omsg
     .To = msg.Subject
     .CC = ""
     .BCC = ""
     .Subject = Thanks
     .Body = (msg.Body + "Thank you for joining Club PFM! You will be receiving your first newsletter with your special Club PFM offer within the next 7 days!")
     .Display
   End With
   'end response
            'try calling other operations, see if they work!!
            'does not work in this fashion, try putting entire code here, then call this on new mail event

            'Call AddAddressesToContacts
            'end calling operations
            ' uncomment the next line to have it only find one unread
            ' message at a time
            'Exit For
        End If
    Next

    ' If you uncommented the line to read individual messages,
    ' comment the next line so you don't get a message box
    ' every single message!

    MsgBox "All messages in Inbox are read", vbInformation, "All Read"
    Exit Sub
eh:
    MsgBox Err.Description, vbCritical, Err.Number
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Each does not keep track well when items are deleted/moved and changes the number of items in the collection.

Use this type of loop.

```
For i = folder.Items.Count To 1 Step -1 
    Set obj = folder.Items(i)
    obj.Move myDestFolder
Next
```